# Configure DCOM on Server Core

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-core, dcom

I'm trying to configure remote access to WMI across a number of servers, however the boxes that are just running Server Core are giving me a headache.

Notionally, in order to do this we need to run `dcomcnfg` and set permissions through that tool for Remote Activiation etc. Server Core, being GUI-less, doesn't have `dcomcnfg` let alone MMC more generally.

Running `dcomcnfg` from a full machine and then adding the server core box for remote administration doesn't give me a "DCOM Config" entry in the tree - I only have "COM+ Applications" and "Distributed Transaction Coordinator" for the remote server.

I've done a few searches, and either can't find the right magical incantation for Google, or what I'm doing is something rarely done.

How are we meant to configure DCOM on a Server Core box?

Comment: You should be able to configure remote WMI access using group policy, no?

Comment: Yes, but I'd like to know how to fiddle with it on a single computer as well. GPO will work, but when it comes to testing configuration out on a single server, GPO can add an extra level of complexity.

Comment: Did you discover a way to configure DCOM?

Answer (score 1):

The WMI service runs automatically by default, so all you need to do is add a firewall exception to allow access:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="windows management instrumentation (wmi)" new enable=yes
```

Or use group policy.

Comment: Firewall is off on this box, so that's not an issue.

Comment: and question was about DCOM, not about WMI